# Know when a parenthesis on string is being close on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, codemirror

I am working with a token on javascript and I wonder if anyone knows a way for knowing if the next token is one closing a parenthesis.

For example: Let's say we have the string `"$(var8(today())) - $(storm())"`

How can I know that the parenthesis that is between `$` and `var8` is being closed?

I could not found any boolean function for that or couldn't come in a simple way.

I have tried using REgrex but it turns the function really complex.

I am using the codemirror Api [codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api)

Comment: That depends on the use-case, if you only want to know if the parenthesis match, you would loop over each char in the string and increase/decrease the parenthesis counter base on the occurrence of `(` or `)` , and ensure that it is never negative, and `0` at the end of the string.

Comment: If the linked duplicate does not answer the question, you need to explain why.

Comment: You need to check for balanced parentheses/brackets.However that will just tell you if there is an extra closing/opening one not *where*. You need more complex analysis to find out which one is missing. And yes, this shouldn't be done with regex, as it's infinitely recursive and rather complex when you have repeatedly nested regex expressions (which some regex engines have native support for but it's still annoying).

Comment: If you have a more complex scenario you would write a tokenizer and a lexer.

Comment: i think this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969755/how-to-check-the-sequence-of-opening-and-closing-brackets-in-string

Comment: @t.niese I am using the codemirror api. I think I could use the method eatWhile with a Regex expression. codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api